# VB.Net Application settings ignored when app starts at Windows login

Tags: vb.net, startup

I have a VB.Net client app that utilizes application settings (eg "My.Settings.showClock").
I recently added the ability to run the application at Windows login time by adding the executable to the registry.

Simplified sample code:

```
Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run", True)
regKey.SetValue(Application.ProductName, """" & Application.ExecutablePath & """")
regKey.Close()
```

**The problem is that when the app does start automatically at login, it ignores all the settings and opens with the default settings.**
Does anyone know why this is happening and how to prevent it?
The executable that is added to the registry is fine; it opens the app no problem from the command line.

The app is compiled with the .Net target framework 4.6.2.

As for adding the app to the 'startup' program group - I cannot do this, as my company does not allow it.

Comment: If you are not logged in yet, then the application would normally use the settings for the default user. Use the registry section for the default user perhaps.

Comment: My apologies for the improper wording.  I did not mean boot time.  The application starts during Windows login.

Comment: Surely *during* is more improper wording, you'd hope it starts *after* login.  A simple explanation is that the setting scope is User, and it hasn't been saved yet.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was going on: I am using the one-click publishing of the app, and the built-in settings functionality. When you execute this type of app using the executable path (the .exe file), it will open using its own settings.  Opening using the start menu shortcut, which is an application reference file, it will use a different set of settings. I don't know why this is; just that it works that way. So when the program runs at windows logon it used the executable path; thus it was not utilizing the same settings as the start menu, and looked like the default settings.
Anyway, there were 2 ways to fix this: 1. Do not use the built-in settings (my.Settings); store them yourself in the registry.  or 2. Change the run at startup to use the application reference instead.  I chose method 2 and it worked.  Below is the code.

```
Dim applicationName As String = Application.ProductName
Dim applicationPath As String
Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey

Const REG_RUN_KEY As String = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"

'Company name s/b publisher, so make sure publisher and company name are the same, or hard-code.
'Product s/b product name from the publish options, so make sure ProductName from assembly matches product name from publish options, or hard code.
applicationPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs) + "\" + Application.CompanyName + "\" + Application.ProductName + ".appref-ms"

regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(REG_RUN_KEY, True)
regKey.SetValue(applicationName, """" & applicationPath & """")
regKey.Close()
```

Also note that I'm using 'runOnce' instead of 'run', to prevent leaving a remnant there if the app is uninstalled.